# Import Error: Missing DLL on Windows 7 when trying to import Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, scikit-learn

Details:

Python 3.2 (32 bit install)
Windows 7 64 bit

Code inducing the error:

```
from sklearn import svm
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chrismv48\workspace\Python Datamining\Biological_Response.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import svm
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\classes.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseLibSVM
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import libsvm, liblinear
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried some of the solutions proposed in other missing DLL threads, but with no success...

Comment: How did you install the sklearn package?  Did you use the pre-built 64 bit binaries available here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn?

Comment: 32-bit Python requires 32-bit extensions. Make sure you installed the the right package.

Comment: Chris, could you provide us with a bit more information on how you installed scikit-learn?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In case you are using the binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn. They require [numpy-MKL](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), as indicated on the download page. The official numpy binaries won't work.

Comment: Whoops, thought I had! Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You can run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and look for *LoadImage* events from your python process to see what LoadImage failed.

You'll probably want to use the procmon gui, but [here is a good reference for using it from the command line](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/microsoft-windows/9780735662728/4dot-process-monitor/id3114354).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to scan your module for dependencies and satisfy them.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The tool can load python files too. (worked on a *.pyd file) Didn't solve my problem with cv2 in the end, but it's a valid suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

did a lot of Google search, asked people, and struggled quite long for DLL not found(from sklearn import svm)
using Windows7 64bit 
Finally everything worked out fine after updating the version of Anaconda.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer